# Stripe billing portal for connected account customers

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

Normally when dealing with stripe api using nodejs, the second parameter in most functions is an object that contains "stripeAccount" referring to the "connected accounts id".

However the second parameter of stripe.billingPortal.sessions.create is an access token.

What is the correct way to create a billing portal session for my connected accounts customer?

When passing stripeAccount to the second parameter i get the following error:

`Stripe: Unknown arguments ([object Object]). Did you mean to pass an options object?`

```
        const session = await stripe.billingPortal.sessions.create({
            customer: customer.CustomerId,
            return_url: getRedirectUrl(req),
        }, { stripeAccount: connected.AccountId });
```

I notice there is another parameter "on_behalf_of"

However when i send the accountId to that parameter is get an error "customer does not exist"

`Error occured StripeInvalidRequestError: No such customer: 'cus_xxx'`

```
        const session = await stripe.billingPortal.sessions.create({
            customer: customer.CustomerId,
            return_url: getRedirectUrl(req),
            on_behalf_of: connected.AccountId
        });
```

Comment: your first example works fine for me if I pass in the relevant ids on my own account. What version of the stripe-node SDK are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `stripe-account` header is a bit like using the connected account's API keys - the request is made as if authenticated as the connected account. It means the objects are created on that account, and the reference objects (e.g. Customer) have to exist on that account.

The `on_behalf_of` parameter is not like that. The request is authenticated as your account, so the object will be created on your account, and reference Customer must exist on your account. What `on_behalf_of` does is define how funds settlement should be handled (i.e. using the currency set up of that account).
Note that `stripe-account` should have the same effect as `on_behalf_of`, with the addition of authenticating the requests as the connected account.

As such, you're getting no error with `stripe-account`, presumably because the Customer you're passing exists on the connected account. With `on_behalf_of`, you're getting a `no such customer` error, presumably because the Customer doesn't exist on your account.

I think it's easy to get confused by reading the Stripe documentation, because they use the wording 'making an API call on behalf of a connected account' when talking about the `stripe-account` header, which is confusingly close to the `on_behalf_of` parameter.
`stripe-account` authenticates the request on behalf of the connected account.
`on_behalf_of` handles settlement as per the connected account's configuration.

To answer your question directly, I believe you should be using `stripe-account` and not `on_behalf_of`.

Comment: Hmmmm, so if you read my question, it tells you that the second parameter does not expect an object so i cant use stripeAccount like i do on other calls